# Writing to Django-mapped tables from outside the project

Tags: django, django-models

Is there anything specifically that I should do or refrain from doing? The only thing I have found so far is that I should create the tables initially using Django's ORM.

I haven't found any resources specific to this topic which makes me think the answer is either very obvious or that this isn't done much, which probably means it's a bad idea.

*Details*: I have a standalone C# program that reads a file and exports the data to a PostgreSQL database.  I would like to make a website where users can upload these types of files and query the data generated by the program.  I really like python and I have done a number of projects with it (but not Django), and my experience with C# and .NET so far has been fairly negative.  I have also done the Django tutorial, some of Tango, and I'm reading *Two Scoops of Django*, all of which make me think I will like working with Django.

Comment: I can't think of a reason not to do this. Data is data, whether you write it from Django or C#.

Comment: That was my intuition, but I just wanted to be sure.